# How to access related models in RoR after using link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use wkhtmltopdf to convert a page to pdf

```
<%= link_to "download" user_group_assessments_path(@user, @group, @assessment, format: 'pdf') =>
```

It will go to my AssessmentsController and call my index method, it looks like:

```
@assessments = Assessment.all 
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.pdf do
  render pdf: "filename"
  template: "assessments/show.pdf.erb"
 end
 end
 end
```

In show.pdf.erb I access user, group and assessment.

Every thing is ok and it works without any problem. But when I call

```
<% @assessment.measurements.each do |m| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined method 'measurements' for nil:NilClass

And it points to the line where I am trying to access measurement.

How can I access the model 'measurement' from this file?

Comment: you have a syntax error in your call to link_to. Instead of a closing tag (`%>`) you're using `=>`

Comment: This error is just here, in my program every thing is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above, I wrote the following code in index action:

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "filename"
    template: "assessments/show.pdf.erb"
  end
end
```

But that was wrong, because I am trying to access @assessment, where the @assessment defined in show action, not in index action. In index all assessments are defined, not a specific one. And I need just one with a specific id.

Also, putting the code in show method instead of index solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your assessment details to your view. for example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "filename"
    template: "assessments/show.pdf.erb"
    locals: {:assessment => @assesment}
  end
end
```

Then in your view assessment can be accessed as

```
<% assessment.measurements.each do |m| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Assessment can be found, but measurement not. In the database every assessment has many measurements, so it finds the assessment but not the related measurements. @miche

Answer (score 0):

In controller your variable is `@assessments` but for iteration you are trying to use `@assessment` which is missing plural `s`. Try as following

```
<% @assessments.each do |assessment| %>
     <% assessment.measurements.each do |m| %>
        ...
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or, you must need an `@assessment` instance variable in your controller action. and then you can use following loop

```
<% @assessment.measurements.each do |m| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: It is not the problem. The same code will be called from two files: show.pdf.erb and show.html.erb. The differece is that .pdf.erb (this case) will be called from the index of the controller with format pdf, therefore it find assessment id but it cann't find the related measurements (measurement is saved as other model in db)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this if you have an association with measurements

```
@assessments = Assessments.joins(:measurements)
```

and in your view do this

`@assessments.each do |assessment|
    assessment.measurements.each do |measurement|
       perform operations
    end
end`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. I think you are nearby the solution. The problem is that the measurements (other model where every assessment has many measurements) cann't be found. I should send the measurements but I don't know how, so that they could be found there. @DivyaSharma

Comment: Can't you find Assessment with assessment id and then its related measurements?

Comment: I can find the assessment and assessment id, but not the measurment. 

The same code (draw.js.erb) will be called from two files: show.pdf.erb and show.html.erb. The differece is that show.pdf.erb (this case) will be called from the index of the controller with format pdf, therefore it find assessment id but it cann't find the related measurements.

Also when I call draw.js.erb from the file show.html.erb of the method show there is no problem, but when I call it from .pdf.erb, the measurements cann't be found.